# Power View Report in Excel dont work in Share Point 2013 web site

Tags: excel-services, performancepoint, powerview

I use `Share Point 2013` and `SQL Server 2008 R2` and `Performance Point Service` and I use `Excel Service` for show `Excel Report` in `SharePoint 2013` web site.

My SharePoint web site work and I can view `Excel Report` in my web site.

But when I use a Excel report that have `Power View` , It don't show?!?

this is my excel report :

[image]

I use simple data for `Power View` Data Source from first sheet.

And then I create a Power view report and use my `Data Set` like this picture :

[image]

In this tab I can view my `Power View Report`.

Then I load this `Excel Report` to my `Share Point Document` :

[image]

But when I want see this file I see this report like this :

[image]

[image]

I installed `Silverlight 5.1` in my PC . Why tab of `Power View` don't show in my browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you need SQL 2012 SP 1 to use PowerView with SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Can I upgrade `SQL Server 2008 Of my SharePoint 2013` to `SQL Server 2012 SP 1` with `SQL Serever` Set Up?what will happen for `SharePoint Database` ? Version of this `Database` will convert?

Comment: I am sure you will be able to upgrade though it is worth checking the process as you may need to detach databases etc.

Comment: : hi. Am I force to re Install `SSRS` in New sql server 2012?

Comment: Again, you will need to confirm the requirements for PowerView but it certainly needs additional components over and above the standard database such as the Tabular database and it will also need to be in integrated mode with SharePoint.